# How to allow to adsense ads to work, note that global xss_clean is enabled?

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

As in the title.

I want to allow to adsense ads to work, I'm use `codeigniter` with `grocery-crud` in my work.
The idea is I will add adsense code  to field, then to store it in database, and then will shows in the pages of site.

The problem is when you send the code from field to database, it deletes big part of Adsense code, thus the code does not work.

Now, my question is, **How to allow to this field only to take Adsense code and store it in database without any modification ?**

Comment: If anybody have an inquiry about something required contributes to solve the problem, please say to me.

Answer (score 0):

Save that it as js file and include it[/read it] where/when needed.